# bootstrap button group text shrinking on page resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a group of buttons in a justified button group.

[image: Button group]

When I resize the page I get something like this:

[image: Button group when page size reduced]

What can I do to not let the button text shrink? Maybe stop the page from resizing at a certain limit, or let the buttons become vertical. (Same behavior of default bootstrap behavior)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      Group A
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      Group B
    </button>
  </div>
  ....
```

[A running example on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2F1qgHqpGtYpY35hEKSl?p=preview)

Comment: Give `white-space: normal;` to `.btn`

Comment: On a page containing only a button group it doesn't work, however, it worked on a page containing other content in addition, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop your buttons down on mobile resolution

```
@media(max-width: 480px){
  .btn-group {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set your font size inside `<button>` using vw(viewport width) size unit.
Just include this custom css in your style.css file :

```
.btn-group > button {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

For your information 1vw = 1% of viewport width. Learn more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) 
 
Hope this answer your question.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.btn-group > button {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Group A
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Group B
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Group C
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Group D
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Group E
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Group F
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```